How to format characters in Excel using Graph? (not all characters in cell)
I want to update cells in an Excel file to look like this:

A background color of my choosing with the last two characters in the cell bold and larger font size.
I'm reading the 'Update a range format in Excel' documentation and updating colors and fonts of a cell  is possible, for example:
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/range(address='$A$1')/format/font
Content-type: application/json

{
  "bold": true,
  "color": "#4B180E",
  "size": 26
}

However, I can't find how to manipulate characters (not the entire cell) in the documentation.  Is it possible to do this in Micrsoft Graph, and if so how?

The Graph API doesn't expose any endpoint that will allow you to format part of the text inside the cell.
The issue is that formatting of individual characters in a cell is not supported by underlying js API.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/4623
